# How to create multiple todolists using a save button?

Tags: javascript, html, function, foreach, traversal

Below is a snippet of some of my code. Think a todo list on steriods. I am trying to create multiple Div elements that save to a page that contain a different list every time my "Save button is pressed. whats actually happening is that multiple divs are showing but the original div saved  is the only one that gets updated with the list information(so like in a todo list when you click submit a new list item appears ive added a save button and an input field that the user can use to name their list and saves that list to a container but only one div gets updated). I know i'm almost there but ive been looking at this for a couple of hours now and cant quite figure it out. https://github.com/W33K5Y/TODO-PIRPLE

```
const saveButton = document.getElementById("submit-save");
const myLists = document.getElementById("my-lists");
const startNote = document.getElementById("start-note");
const listName = document.getElementById("new-list-name");
const myUl = document.getElementById("my-ul-lists");

// ! savebutton listener
saveButton.addEventListener("click", addNewTodo);
// ! make new html elements
const newTodoOl = document.createElement("ol");
const newTodoLi = document.createElement("li");
const listH1 = document.createElement("h4");

// ! =============== function for creating new todo ================================
function addNewTodo() {
  const todoDiv = document.querySelector(".todo-container");
  const todos = document.querySelectorAll(".todo-item");
  todos.forEach(function(todo) {
    createLi(todo);
  });
  listName.value ? listH1.innerText = listName.value : listH1.innerText = "My List";
  newTodoDivWrap.classList.add("new-todo-div");
  newTodoDivWrap.appendChild(listH1);
  newTodoDivWrap.appendChild(newTodoOl);
  myLists.appendChild(newTodoDivWrap);
  todoReset(todoDiv, startNote);
  startLoginSignUpNoneLobbyFlex();
}

// todo function to go in above that removes all of whats in the tido-container

function todoReset(div, lobbyDiv) {
  lobbyDiv.remove();
  div.firstElementChild.innerHTML = "";
}

function createLi(todo) {
  // ! Create LI
  const newTodo = document.createElement('li');
  newTodo.innerText = todo.innerText;
  newTodo.classList.add("todo-saved-item");
  newTodoOl.appendChild(newTodo);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the following is why it's not working as you intended:

```
const newTodoOl = document.createElement("ol");
const newTodoLi = document.createElement("li");
const listH1 = document.createElement("h4");
```

Remember that javascript creates references, so when you do something like this—`newTodoDivWrap.appendChild(listH1)`—you don't add a new element, you only add a reference to said element.

It's the same as if you had two objects.

```
var a = {'name': 'Anette'}
var bbbb = a // creates a reference, not a new object.
bbbb.name = 'Bjorn'

console.log(a.name) // Bjorn
```

So create new elements *inside* the method, instead of creating and calling public ones.

---

Also, comments like this are so unnecessary:

```
function createLi(todo) {
  // ! Create LI
```

You had a method name that perfectly explains what it does. You don't need to comment that. Start making it a habit of naming variables or method to explain what's going on—you're already doing that (ex. `startLoginSignUpNoneLobbyFlex`)—so you don't have to use comments. Comments are useless, unless it's for documentation.

Comment: Ok I kind of understand what you mean in regards to js creating references. I'm still a little confused as to how that would effect what I've done. when I hit save I get all the items in the list that I have (like your standard todo list works) but when i hit save for the second time with a brand new list it only extends on to the original list rather than printing out to the page a brand new list

Comment: thank you for taking the time to get back to me and I will take on board about the comments too :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to move

```
const newTodoOl = document.createElement("ol");
const newTodoLi = document.createElement("li");
const listH1 = document.createElement("h4");
```

into the addNewTodo function. That way each iteration produces a brand new List
Rickard pointed me in the right direction :)